# Twitter Bootstrap: Grid system floating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have the following simple html page. It should display Col1 to Col4 horizontally next to each other, but Col4 is in a below the others. Why? And how can I solve it?

I'm using bootstrap 2.2.2

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">  
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 row">
          <div class="span1">Col1</div>
          <div class="span1">Col2</div>
          <div class="span1">Col3</div>
          <div class="span3">Col4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 row">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to nest grid elements you need to specify the `.row` container as a child of your grid element container, this way your grid elements can properly align. The way you have it now the `.row` class won't be able to remove the extra gutter space it eliminates with a negative margin to fit all the columns within your container. You can read more about it [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) under the **Nesting columns** section.

Fixed markup:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:9000/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">  
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="span1">Col1</div>
              <div class="span1">Col2</div>
              <div class="span1">Col3</div>
              <div class="span3">Col4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```